# How to find 2nd and 4th friday in a month using AIX script?

Tags: unix, aix

Please see the following script:

```
day_of_week=`head -1 condition.lst |cut -d'|' -f1`
condition=`head -1 condition.lst |cut -d'|' -f2`
if [ $day_of_week -le 6 ]; then
        echo $condition >>inpfile
fi
```

I think it will add the value in "condition" file to inpfile if the current day is not a saturday. Am I right? Correct me if I am wrong.

Can you help me how to add this "condition" to "inpfile" if the current day is NOT a SECOND or FOURTH Friday in the month?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Arjun

Comment: I would get system permissions and a sofware client to connect to your installed RDMDBS and have it do this calculation. There are likely corner cases you're not anticipating. For example, what do you want to do when a holiday falls on a 2nd or 4th Friday? In any case, this sort of Q is too board by S.O. definitions. You're expected to post your best attempt to solve the problem and people will help you **fix** your problem code. Good luck.

Comment: Did you look at `date '+%w'` or `cal` ?